# Mysql relation in database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I make datatables where I store advertisements.

My advertisement table looks like follows:

```
 Advertisement:
 id (PK)
 title
 description
 category_id (FK)
 ..
```

I have 2 different types of advertisements: I store cars and I store real estate.
Therefore I have attributes which differ for both types. i.e. cars have a brand and number of doors whereas real estate have number of rooms..

Therefore I would like to ask what is the best way to store this relation.

Should I put all values in one big advertisement table, but there is the disatvantage that some values are allways null.

Or should I make 2 additional tables and keep the common values in the advertisement table?

```
CarTable
id(PK)
advertisement_id (FK)
brand
numberOfDoors
...

RealEstateTable
id(PK)
advertisement_id (FK)
nrOfRooms
...
```

I don't think that the second solution with 2 additional tables is very good. 
Any suggestions? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways could be:

```
Advertisement:
id (PK)
title
description
category_id (FK)
..

Attribute type:
id (PK)
name
code (can be optional)

Advertisement's attributes:
id (PK)
Advertisement id (FK)
Attribute id (FK)
Attribute value
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the second one is the right one.
Of course it is dependent of how big is the database and how many are that null columns.
I'm thinking so because:

1. There will be no any empty cells for a difference of types
2. Usually for many column tables we are using 'SELECT * ...' CLAUSE but it isn't good and in your case all these NULL fields will load the traffic
3. At all data base engines are optimized to make relations between tables - in case you have hard defined relation by key it isn't a problem.

Comment: So in that case I have a one to one relation between Advertisement - CarTable  and Advertisement - RealEstateTable? With that solution should I make another attribute in the advertisement table to save the type of the advertisement if it is a car or realestate? What If i make a search on all the entrys of the different table?